# Can interlocking paving stones be installed on a warp/vertical curve?

Tags: driveway, pavers, paving

I have a vertically warped concrete area in front of my garage entry door (badly cracked/damaged).  I’d like to rip it out and replace it with interlocking pavers.  I can’t find any info on if pavers can be warped vertically, it’s all about horizontal curves in pathways.  I figure they can to an extent, but everything seems to talk about perfectly straight grade lines and nothing speaks to if and how much they can be vertically curved.

[image: warped concrete entry]

Comment: If you're gonna be buying the pavers from a store, why not go to the store and lay out some pavers, and see how much the paver mat can flex?

Comment: Typically materials like this have specifications for vertical curves/gaps/angles, I can't find them. Maybe it's strictly not allowed, I don't know.  However, too large a gap between pavers would negate the "interlocking" aspect of the bricks and I certainly wouldn't guess at that gap distance just based on eye-balling it in a store.